# Best way to use qnamaker with V3 MS bot

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I have a bot built using MS bot framework which is on version 3. I have created qnamaker service with basic KB for testing. I was wondering if there is best way to access KB in existing bot which is powered by luis. I do not want to make explicit http call using request module , kb id and KB auth key etc. to get answers out Kb.

I found this npm package has some samples but it usage qna as a recognizer and I already have luis recognizer.

Ref:- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/Node/samples/QnAMaker

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct packages, and set the correct settings. This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/tutorials/create-qna-bot) covers it. If you create a template bot and look at the packages and code, you can add them to your own bot.

Comment: I did it and it has come code content that's mentioned in ref link.